# Yii and database row in dropdown

Tags: yii

I have two model: test1 , test2
And an action in test1 :

```
public function active_widgets_list()
{
    $widgets = SiteWidget::model()->find('status=:status', array(':status' => '1'));
    return $widgets;
}
```

And I will show test1.tbl_1 rows as dropdown list in test2's view:

```
$list=CHtml::listData(SiteWidget::model()->active_widgets_list(), 'id', 'title');
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'widget_id', $list, array('empty' => 'Select Please'));
```

but down't work. i have just an empty dropdown.

Comment: use `findAll` instead of `find`, or is that a typo? Although the list shouldn't be empty, since there will be atleast one model

Comment: @bool.dev not typo. i didn't know what is correct. thanks. fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`findAll`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) instead of `find`, since `find` returns only a single active record with the specified condition.

```
$widgets = SiteWidget::model()->findAll('status=:status', array(':status' => '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gii tools, You don't need any thing for saving. It generate all the codes you need it. It is so easy to make a huge of models, controllers, views and CRUD.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii